Is there a max absolute error loss function?
I'm fitting a small model and need to use a custom loss function. I want to avoid large errors. I thought of a max absolute error function
$$ \text{MaxAE} = \max(|y-y_{pred}|) \, ,$$
with y the measured data and $y_{pred}$ the outcome of my model. I did not try the max squared error loss function yet.
At a first glance, this looks like a good idea. The optimiser should tune the parameters until the worst data point has the same error as the second worse. Then keep on optimising until the two worse catch up with the third worse, etc. My optimisation is not converging though. Moreover, I expect that if this was a good idea, I would have heard about it. Why is this a bad idea? What's wrong with this loss function?

Why do you need a custom loss function? Also, the choice of loss will determine what your model predicts. The max squared error and max absolute error will most likely give you different kinds of forecasts. The fact that you are fine with both indicates that your forecasting problem is not well-defined.

Well actually, it's the other way: I'm not satisfied with any. That's why I'm looking for something else.

Well, the same reasoning applies. You are not looking for a solution to a well-defined problem. You are looking at different problems and hope one of them appeals to you.

The problem with this approach is that when you specify a loss function, it is a cumulative value of loss from all the samples. Thus every data point helps in deciding the parameter change to happen. With using the max loss you specified, you are essentially training one one sample per epoch, making your training incredibly slow and volatile.

The problem with such a function is, as xabash answers, that it only optimizes one point at a time, which is much slower and more volatile than optimizing all points simultaneously. If your goal is to minimize extreme values than a better option is using MSE, which gives a lot more weight to extreme values because of the square while still optimizing all points (or you could use an even higher power for an even greater effect, and so on).
